# Mixed-Frequency VAR -packages

Tags: programming, regression

My intention is to retrieve forecast error variance decomposition from a MF-VAR with no latent processes following Ghysels (2012)

> https://www.hec.ca/finance/seminaires/Ghysels.pdf

I found the following site:

> http://www2.kobe-u.ac.jp/~motegi/Matlab_Codes.html

that has MatLab codes for this, but would be more comfortable with using R instead.

As far as I understand the **mfbvar**-package in R does not bend to this. I also looked at the **midasr**-package, but am not convinced it can do the trick. 
Are  there any relevant packages I am missing or could the aforementioned packages be modified to suit a general MF-VAR?